# Desktop launcher with .png files to the application

Tags: launcher

I have created a desktop launcher for my GUI-application. To the application I have three .png files that is read and used by the GUI itself.
The .png files are located at the same place where I have the application.

I created the launcher with: gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new

Now my problem is that these .png files are not read.
I get 'Failed to load image from file "my.png".

So why are not these .png files read?

Comment: Can you post the content of the `.desktop` file?

Answer (score 0):

I for some reason got it up and running. Sorry I'm not sure what I did wrong in the first place. Nevertheless I put my .png file under /usr/share/applications and now it's working.

Any how. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: OK, I will look into this deeper tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 0):

I see you answered your own question, but I believe it would be better if you copied or moved the image to `/usr/share/pixmaps/`, because `/usr/share/applications/` is intended for .desktop files.

Probably what happened is that your .desktop file (launcher) was trying to load the image from a relative path 'my.png'. When you moved the image to this directory the problem was "solved". It should work if you place your image under the pixmaps dir I mentioned before and reference it in your desktop file with an absolute path, e.g. `/usr/share/pixmaps/my.png`

To use a relative path you would need to create an application icon, those are stored under `/usr/share/icons`, but I wouldn't know how to approach this.